# how to create a simple menu in python and used to do several task, such as calculating maximum,minimum and so on

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a simple python menu, which let the user pick an option and the program call the function to work out certain things, such as calculating maximum and minimum value from a data file. The problem I am having is there is error in my third option(C), for which I been looking for a solution from days. I tried researching, reading books but couldn't really fix the problem.

Here how the code looks like.

```
import statistics
import math

f = open('results.txt', 'r')
row=[]
for line in f:
    row.append([float(x) for x in line.split()])
print('Abrar_data')
print('')
print(row)
f.close

ans=True
while ans:
    print ("""
    A.Maximum and the minimum value of the experimental results.
    B.Calculate the average value and the standard deviation value of the
    experimental results.
    C.How many experiments resulted in values greater than some input value.
    D.Sort the experiments data (4th row) in ascending and descending order.
    E.To Exit the menue enter 'E' or press Enter
    """)
    ans=input("What would you like to do? ") 

    if ans=="A":
      def largest(row, row_number):
        largest=row[row_number][0]
        for i in range (1, 50):
          if largest < row[row_number][i]:
            largest=row[row_number][i]
        return largest
      def smallest(row, row_number):
        smallest=row[row_number][0]
        for i in range (1, 50):
          if smallest > row[row_number][i]:
            smallest=row[row_number][i]
        return smallest
      row_number=3
      print('')
      print('The maximum is:',largest(row,row_number),'and the minimum is:',smallest(row,row_number)) 
      print('')



    elif ans=="B":
      def average(row, row_number):
        import statistics
        average=row[row_number][0]
        for i in range(1, 50):
          average=statistics.mean(row[row_number])
        return average
      row_number=3
      def standard_deviation(row, row_number):
        import statistics
        standard_deviation=row[row_number][0]
        for i in range(1,50):
          standard_deviation=statistics.stdev(row[row_number])
        return standard_deviation

      print('')
      print('The average value is:',average(row,row_number),'and the standard deviation value is:',standard_deviation(row, row_number))
      print('')

    elif ans=="C":
      print('') 
      count=0
      x = int(input('Enter a number to compare it with Experiment data'))
      for i in (row):
          if i > x:
             count=count+1
             print('')
             print('How many experiments resulted in values greater than some input value',count)
             print('')
    elif ans=="D":
           Bubble sort


      print('Sort the experiments data (4th row) in ascending and descending order.')


    elif ans=="E":
        break



    elif ans !="":
      print('Invaild input ')
```

the error I am getting for the option "C" is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Main User\Documents\University work\Engineering Programming and design\abrar_data.py", line 71, in <module>
    if i > x:
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
```

If anyone understand the error and can help then I will really appreciate your help. PS I am using python 3.5

Comment: the code didn't really turn out so well here, sorry for that, I'm new here, so still learning, thanks

Comment: The Function "C" should be able to calculate how many experiments resulted (which is a row in the data file)  in values greater than some input value

Comment: In the future, your questions will be better if you reduce them to the minimal code that shows the problem. Many times, the process of doing this will guide you to the solution yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to compare a list with an integer.

For example:

```
>>> [] > 2
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
```

Make sure all the elements in the list (row) are integers.

You can check this by adding following code to you script.

```
print (all(isinstance(x,int) for x in row))
```